# How to do incremental loading in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables `product_source` (with 50 records) and `product_target` (no records).

```
create table product_source
(
     productId varchar(10),
     productName varchar(50),
     productStatus varchar(20),
     productType varchar(20),
     productDesc varchar(50)
)

create table product_target
(
     productId varchar(10),
     productName varchar(50),
     productStatus varchar(20),
     productType varchar(20),
     productDesc varchar(50)
)
```

Sample data in `product_source` table:

```
productId productName   productStatus productType productDesc   
-------   ----------     -----------  -----------  -----------  
111          lenova       pending      computer   hp_computer   
222          pendrive     delivered    gadget     storage
777          harddisk     pending      storage    storagedevice
...50 records
```

I loaded the data into target table using insert statement for example.

```
insert into product_target as 
    select * 
    from product_source     -- 50 records loaded
```

`product_target` table:

```
productId productName   productStatus productType productDesc    
-------   ----------     -----------  -----------  -----------   
111          lenova       pending      computer   hp_computer   
222          pendrive     delivered    gadget     storage
...50 records got loaded
```

Now again some data (for example 100 new records) got loaded into source table `product_source`, now how to load only those 100 new records into `product_target` table with column `is_status` stating whether any new record inserted/updated in source then it should add as below.

`product_source` table (with the new records):

```
productId productName   productStatus productType productDesc   
-------   ----------     -----------  -----------  -----------  
111          samsung       delivered    mobile     sam_mobile     
989          scandisk     inprogress    pendrive   pendrive_64gb
546          mouse        inprogress    computer   mouse_computer
666          keyboard     inprogress    computer   keyboard_computer
777          harddisk     delivered     storage    storagedevice
...100 records
```

`product_target` table:

```
productId productName   productStatus productType productDesc    Is_status
-------   ----------     -----------  -----------  -----------   ----------
555          lenova       pending       computer   hp_computer       inserted
111          lenova       delivered     computer   hp_computer       updated  
777          harddisk     delivered     storage    storagedevice     updated
989          scandisk     inprogress    pendrive   pendrive_64gb     inserted
546          mouse        inprogress    computer   mouse_computer    inserted
666          keyboard     inprogress    computer   keyboard_computer inserted
...
```

Similarly if load happens every day in `product_source` table, then how to load every new inserted/updated recorded in `product_target` table?

I used merge statement in loading from `product_source` to `product_target`...but no getting. Could anyone look into this?

Comment: please show us your `merge` query and also kindly explain what does `no getting.` means

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by two ways,
1. In SSIS, By using SCD transformation or Lookup Transformation you can do incremental Loading.
2. second way is by writing Merge statement in Sql server we can do Incremental Loading.

Answer (score 0):

You could output your "100 new records" you are updating/inserting to product_source into temp tables.

Then join the temp tables to the product_target table for inserting/updating.

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/156204/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the primary key on the table is `productId`

```
insert into product_target (
 productId,
 productName,
 productStatus,
 productType,
 productDesc
 )
    select 
 productId,
 productName,
 productStatus,
 productType,
 productDesc
    from product_source SRC
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM product_target TGT 
                      WHERE TGT.productID = SRC.ProductId);
```

Note: you should *always* use column lists when inserting and selecting like this.

In my opinion:

*Don't* use a temp table to store the things you inserted. This is redundant and over complicated since you already know whats in the target table so why go store it in another separate table

I suggest that you *don't* use SSIS to do it. Where source and target tables are in the same database, a T-SQL solution is often best, unless you have wider requirements (like logging, configuration, complex scheduling, lots of tables etc.). The SCD component is inefficient for large data sets (it's fine for a few thousand records but don't get into the habit of using it). Also the SCD component is a 'destructive wizard' - it deletes and recreates the flows every time. The Lookup component is also more ineffecient that T-SQL.