# how to select from sql database where data not in table1 need to select from table2 +asp.net vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have two table FixedAssetMaster_ora and FixedAssetMaster_old. What i want to do is check first if the data exist in FixedAsset_old or not. If exist, select dta from that table, if not exist, need to select data from FixedAssetMaster_ora.Currently my code always select data from FixedAssetMaster_ora.

here is my code:

```
 Dim reccount As String = 0
        Conn = New SqlConnection
        Conn.ConnectionString = ConnStr
        Conn.Open()
        cmd = New SqlCommand

        cmd.CommandText = "Select COUNT(*) FROM FixedAssetMaster_old WHERE ASSET_NUMBER=" & AssetTxt.Text & " And LOC_DEPT=" & DeptTxt.Text & " AND UNIT_NO='" & UnitNoTxt.Text & "' AND (DATEPART(MM, UPDATE_DATE) = " & nowMonth & ") AND (DATEPART(yyyy, UPDATE_DATE) =" & nowYear & ") ;"
        cmd.Connection = Conn
        rdmysql = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If rdmysql.Read = True Then
            'reccount = rdmysql.GetString(0)
            reccount = Val(rdmysql.GetInt32(0))
        End If
        cmd.Dispose()
        rdmysql.Close()
        If reccount = 0 Then
            strsql = "Select * FROM FixedAssetMaster_old WHERE ASSET_NUMBER=" & AssetTxt.Text & " AND LOC_DEPT=" & DeptTxt.Text & " AND UNIT_NO='" & UnitNoTxt.Text & "' And (DATEPART(MM, UPDATE_DATE) = " & nowMonth & ") And (DATEPART(yyyy, UPDATE_DATE) =" & nowYear & ") ;"
            cmd.Connection = Conn
            cmd.CommandText = strsql
            rdmysql = cmd.ExecuteReader

            If rdmysql.Read = True Then
                If rdmysql.IsDBNull(rdmysql.GetOrdinal("ASSET_KEY_SEGMENT3")) = False Then LocationTxt.Text = rdmysql.GetString(rdmysql.GetOrdinal("ASSET_KEY_SEGMENT3"))
                'If rdmysql.IsDBNull(rdmysql.GetOrdinal("REMARKS")) = False Then RemarksTxt.Text = rdmysql.GetString(rdmysql.GetOrdinal("REMARKS"))
                'If rdmysql.IsDBNull(rdmysql.GetOrdinal("REMARKS")) = False Then DDLRemarks.Text = rdmysql.GetString(rdmysql.GetOrdinal("REMARKS"))
            End If
            cmd.Dispose()
            rdmysql.Close()


        ElseIf reccount = 1 Then

            strsql = "Select * FROM FixedAssetMaster_Ora WHERE ASSET_NUMBER=" & AssetTxt.Text & " AND LOC_DEPT='" & DeptTxt.Text & " ';"
            cmd.Connection = Conn
            cmd.CommandText = strsql
            rdmysql = cmd.ExecuteReader

            If rdmysql.Read = True Then
                If rdmysql.IsDBNull(rdmysql.GetOrdinal("ASSET_KEY_SEGMENT3")) = False Then LocationTxt.Text = rdmysql.GetString(rdmysql.GetOrdinal("ASSET_KEY_SEGMENT3"))
                'If rdmysql.IsDBNull(rdmysql.GetOrdinal("REMARKS")) = False Then RemarksTxt.Text = rdmysql.GetString(rdmysql.GetOrdinal("REMARKS"))
                'If rdmysql.IsDBNull(rdmysql.GetOrdinal("REMARKS")) = False Then DDLRemarks.Text = rdmysql.GetString(rdmysql.GetOrdinal("REMARKS"))
            End If
            cmd.Dispose()
            rdmysql.Close()

        End If
```

Can someone help me regarding this matter. Thank you in advance

Comment: Here is a SQL solution to this question. What you have written is an RBAR (row by agonising row) solution which will be very slow and inefficient for large datasets. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50595080/how-to-do-incremental-loading-in-sql-server/50598378#50598378

Comment: Are the columns you want identical in both the tables? You can run a union query and get 1 resultset without doing the checks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments, I have re-worked this answer and created a quick/small Unit Test project to verify its functionality is what I understand of the problem.

```
<TestMethod()>
Public Sub TestGetRecordFromDatabase()
    Dim targetRecord As String = "Jay2"

    Dim recordIn_OldTable As Boolean = DoesRecordExistIn_Old(targetRecord)

    Dim targetTable = "JayV_old"
    If Not recordIn_OldTable Then
        targetTable = "JayV_ora"
    End If

    Dim connectionString As String = "Server=MyDBServer; Database=TestingDB; Trusted_Connection=True;"
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        conn.Open()

        Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM " & targetTable & " where name = @name"

        Using command As SqlCommand = conn.CreateCommand()
            command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "name", .DbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, .Value = targetRecord})
            command.Connection = conn
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            command.CommandText = sql

            Dim dataReader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader

            While dataReader.Read
                Dim name As String = dataReader.GetString(dataReader.GetOrdinal("name"))
                Dim address As String = dataReader.GetString(dataReader.GetOrdinal("address"))
            End While
        End Using
        conn.Close()
    End Using

End Sub

Public Function DoesRecordExistIn_Old(targetRecord As String) As Boolean
    Dim connectionString As String = "Server=MyDBServer; Database=TestingDB; Trusted_Connection=True;"
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        conn.Open()

        Dim sql As String = "SELECT count(*) FROM JayV_old where name = @name"

        Using command As SqlCommand = conn.CreateCommand()
            command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "name", .DbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, .Value = targetRecord})
            command.Connection = conn
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            command.CommandText = sql

            Dim objResult As Object = command.ExecuteScalar()
            Dim rowCount As Int32 = Int32.Parse(objResult)

            If rowCount = 0 Then
                Return False
            Else
                Return True
            End If
        End Using
        conn.Close()
    End Using
End Function
```

I re-created parts of your problem to encompass the logic of the code you have shared. I believe this works as you would like:

- Check for existence of record in **_old** table
- If it exists, load record from **_old** table
- If it does not exist, load record from **_ora** table

I also re-factored the code to make it easier to maintain as the only difference between the two record retrievals is the Table Name, *_old* or *_ora*

Comment: when i change, there is no data be selected from database

Comment: @hasni When you look at the database directly, outside of your application, can you see the required data in the correct tables?

Comment: yes. I can see. For now one table have data another table don't have data. my application should get the data from table that have data.

Comment: And which table is the one that has the data?

Comment: table FixedAssetMaster_Ora. Get data from table FixedAssetMaster_Ora and save it to table FixedAssetMaster_old. Then for the next searching it will show data from FixedAssetMaster_old

Comment: @hasni I added a small change to my answer, I think that will get you further along

Comment: @hasni I have re-worked my answer, hopefully this will work for you now

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with VB but in C# you can do this as:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    cmd.CommandText = "Select count(*) from FixedAssetMaster_old WHERE ASSET_NUMBER=" & AssetTxt.Text & " And LOC_DEPT=" & DeptTxt.Text & " AND UNIT_NO='" & UnitNoTxt.Text & "' AND (DATEPART(MM, UPDATE_DATE) = " & nowMonth & ") AND (DATEPART(yyyy, UPDATE_DATE) =" & nowYear & ") ;";
    cmd.Connection = con;
    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        con.Open();
    }
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.HasRows)
    {
        //Select from FixedAssetMaster_old table
    }
    else
    {
        //Select FROM FixedAssetMaster_Ora table
    }
```